# unnest in tidyr 1.1.0 errors with Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1024 Kb

Tags: r, tidyr

An analysis which was working with an older version of tidyr (around April 2020) now (June 2020) fails, after updating most of my packages, with almost the same code :

Code for tidyr 1.1.0 (to remove warning)

```
Model_Coeff <-  tidyr::unnest(Model_Coeff, cols = "Coeffs_model")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1024 Kb
```

(Working on Windows, R 3.6.3,  32GB RAM, all packages up to date as of today). `unnest` runs for several minutes before filling up the memory and then throwing the error.

Older code which was working but now also fails with

```
Model_Coeff <-  tidyr::unnest(Model_Coeff)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1024 Kb
In addition: Warning message:
`cols` is now required when using unnest().
Please use `cols = c(Coeffs_model)`
```

Luckily for me there is also a function called `unnest_legacy` with which my analysis still works i.e.

```
Model_Coeff <- tidyr::unnest_legacy(Model_Coeff)
```

Model_Coeff is a tibble with

```
dim(Model_Coeff)
[1] 30450     5
```

Which looks like :

```
Browse[3]> head(Model_Coeff)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   protein_Id, peptide_Id [6]
  protein_Id                           peptide_Id                Coeffs_model     isSingular nrcoef
  <chr>                                <chr>                     <list>           <lgl>       <int>
1 CON__A2I7N3~0~NA                     DILSQLGIK~3951            <df[,5] [5 x 5]> FALSE           5
2 CON__A2I7N3~0~NA                     FSISSHYQLK~8659           <df[,5] [5 x 5]> FALSE           5
3 CON__A2I7N3~0~NA                     LTPETLTR~19235            <df[,5] [5 x 5]> FALSE           5
4 CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000007350~1~NA LLLFSPSVVR~17621          <df[,5] [5 x 5]> FALSE           5
5 CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000007350~1~NA LLLPDSLTTWEIHGVSLSK~17642 <df[,5] [5 x 5]> FALSE           5
6 CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000018574~4~NA DYDLVGALR~5077            <df[,5] [5 x 5]> FALSE           5
```

Q: Why is the default version of unnest not working anymore with my tibble in Version 1.1.0?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has changed, but in the past I have had to change some of my legacy code to use `unnest_wider` or `unnest_longer` instead of the old `unnest` function.

Comment: this isn't reproducible OP. If you could include code for recreating the model then I'm happy to help.